# UNIX domain datagram - "Invalid argument" on sendto

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, posix

I am constructing UNIX domain datagram sockets to pass messages from one thread to another thread in the same program.  The socket code is written in C and it's called from NASM.

Sendto returns (through perror) "socket: Invalid argument."

Here is the code for sendto:

```
ssize_t client_send(int64_t sfd, const void * buf, int64_t msgLen, const void * svaddr)
{
    ssize_t result = sendto(sfd, buf, msgLen, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
     perror("socket");
    if (result != msgLen)
        return -1;

    return result;
}
```

Here is how I call client_send from NASM:

```
mov rdi,[socket_client_fd]      ; int64_t sfd
lea rsi,[socket_buffer]     ; const void * buf
mov rdx,720             ; msgLen
lea rcx,[socket_server_addr]    ; (struct sockaddr *) &svaddr
mov r8,r15
call client_send wrt ..plt
```

The server socket is constructed like this:

```
int64_t * create_socket_server()
{
    struct sockaddr_un svaddr, claddr;
    int sfd, j;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    socklen_t len;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    static int64_t retvals[2];

    retvals[0] = 0;
    retvals[1] = 0;

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); /* Create server socket */

    if (sfd == -1)
         return retvals;

    /* Construct well-known address and bind server socket to it */

    if (remove(SV_SOCK_PATH) == -1 && errno != ENOENT)
           return retvals;

    memset(&svaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    svaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(svaddr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(svaddr.sun_path) - 1);

    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
           return retvals;

    retvals[0] = sfd;
    retvals[1] = (int64_t)&svaddr;

     return retvals;
}
```

At the point of the call to sendto, the two endpoints are connected because socket_server_fd (file descriptor) is 4 and  socket_client_fd is 5.

```
; Open the Socket Server
call create_socket_server wrt ..plt
mov rdi,rax
mov rax,[rdi]
mov [socket_server_fd],rax
mov rax,[rdi+8]
mov [socket_server_addr],rax
```

The socket server is initialized like this:

```
Open_Socket_Server:
call create_socket_server wrt ..plt
mov rdi,rax
mov rax,[rdi]
mov [socket_server_fd],rax
mov [rdi+8],rax
mov [socket_server_addr],rax
```

Debugging with gdb at the point of the call, perror returns "socket: Invalid argument."

The message being passed is a qword array of 90 elements (720 bytes).

I can't spot the invalid argument in the client_send code above.  Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to `socket_server_addr`/`svaddr`, in particular not keeping track of what's a pointer and what's not. Casting a `const void **` (note 2 `*`s) to a `struct sockaddr *` is very suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm updating it now.

Comment: retvals[1] = (int64_t)&svaddr; hem, you're returning *a pointer to a variable with automatic storage duration*.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - socket_server_addr appears to be the problem.  It has not been initialized at that point.  I will work on it and post back.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question.  Socket server had been initialized, but the variable socket_server_addr had not been assigned.  Now it has, but I still get "Invalid argument."

Comment: You made `retvals` be `static` for a reason. That same reason applies to `svaddr`.

Comment: By the way, what's with all the assembly? Why not write your program in pure C to get it working, and then convert bits to assembly later if you need to?

Comment: Transposition.  socket_server_addr should be preceded by "mov rax,[rdi+8]" but it's written opposite (mov [rdi+8],rax).  I'm changing that now.

Comment: Okay, but you still didn't address my point about `svaddr`, or why you're using assembly at all.

Comment: Writing both ends in C makes sense so, with no solution in sight, I will do that now.  Your first comment about svaddr cast with two asterisks - the signature from the man pages show "const struct sockaddr *dest_addr" with one asterisk (https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto), so I'm not sure what your comment means.

Comment: Actually you have two different `svaddr`s, and there's a different problem with each. For the one in `client_send`, `svaddr` is a `const void *`, which means `&svaddr` is a `const void **`. Casting the latter to `struct sockaddr *` seems like the wrong thing to do. For the one in `create_socket_server`, you're using a reference to it after it's gone out of scope and been deallocated.