# "Invalid argument" on sendto with UNIX domain datagram socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, posix

The following C programs create socket server and client server, and functions to sendto and recvfrom a UNIX domain datagram socket, to send messages from multiple threads on the client send to a single receiver thread on the server side.

The client and server endpoints are created without error, but when I call client_send, I get "invalid argument" and the function fails.

I posted an earlier question on this ([UNIX domain datagram - "Invalid argument" on sendto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580229/unix-domain-datagram-invalid-argument-on-sendto)) and one useful reply said he suspected const struct sockaddr * svaddr as not correct.  However, the signature of client_send comes directly from the Linux man pages (https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto):

```
ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

Accordingly, my call mirrors the signature from the Linux man page:

```
ssize_t result = sendto(sfd, buf, msgLen, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
```

As a test, I tried changing svaddr pointer the call to eliminate the cast:

```
ssize_t result = sendto(sfd, buf, msgLen, 0, svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
```

But I get the same "Invalid argument" error message.

Here is the C code:

```
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "tlpi_hdr_sockets.h"
#include "ud_ucase_sockets.h"
#include "error_functions_sockets.h"
#include "get_num_sockets.h"
#include "errno.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 750 /* Max size of messages between client to server */
#define SV_SOCK_PATH "/tmp/ud_ucase"

int64_t * create_socket_server(int64_t retvals[])
{
    struct sockaddr_un svaddr, claddr;
    int sfd, j;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    socklen_t len;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    retvals[0] = 0;
    retvals[1] = 0;

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); /* Create server socket */

    if (sfd == -1)
         return retvals;

    /* Construct well-known address and bind server socket to it */

    if (remove(SV_SOCK_PATH) == -1 && errno != ENOENT)
           return retvals;

    memset(&svaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    svaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(svaddr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(svaddr.sun_path) - 1);

    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
        return retvals;

    retvals[0] = sfd;
    retvals[1] = (int64_t)&svaddr;

     return retvals;
}

int64_t * create_socket_client(int64_t retvals[])
{
    struct sockaddr_un claddr;
    int sfd, j;
    size_t msgLen;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    char resp[BUF_SIZE];

    retvals[0] = 0;
    retvals[1] = 0;

    /* Create client socket; bind to unique pathname (based on PID) */

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sfd == -1)
        return retvals;

    memset(&claddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    claddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    snprintf(claddr.sun_path, sizeof(claddr.sun_path), "/tmp/ud_ucase_cl.%ld", (long) getpid());

    retvals[0] = sfd;
    retvals[1] = (int64_t)&claddr;

     return retvals;
}

ssize_t client_send(int sfd, const void * buf, size_t msgLen, const struct sockaddr * svaddr)
{
    ssize_t result = sendto(sfd, buf, msgLen, 0, svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

     perror("socket");

    if (result != msgLen)
        return 0;

    return result;
}

int64_t server_receive(int64_t sfd, void * buf, int64_t msgLen, const void * claddr)
{
    socklen_t * len = (socklen_t * ) sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
    int numBytes = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) claddr, len);

    if (numBytes == -1)
    return 0;

    return numBytes;
}

int close_socket(socket_fd)
{
    int closed = close(socket_fd);
    return closed;
}
```

The C programs are called from NASM, where the parameters in the C function header are passed in rdi, rsi, rdx and rcx:

```
; Open the socket client
lea rdi,[retvals_cli] ; a 2-element int64 array
call create_socket_client wrt ..plt
mov rdi,rax
mov rax,[rdi]
mov [socket_client_fd],rax
mov rax,[rdi+8]
mov [socket_client_addr],rax

; Open the Socket Server
lea rdi,[retvals_svr] ; a 2-element int64 array
call create_socket_server wrt ..plt
mov rdi,rax
mov rax,[rdi]
mov [socket_server_fd],rax
mov rax,[rdi+8]
mov [socket_server_addr],rax

; Client_send
mov edi,[socket_client_fd]
mov rsi,[rbp-24]
mov rdx,720
lea rcx,[socket_server_addr]
mov r8,r15
call client_send wrt ..plt
```

The invalid parameter is in this line of client_send:

```
    ssize_t result = sendto(sfd, buf, msgLen, 0, svaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
```

My only problem is that, after hours of trying different ways to pass parameters and call it, I still don't know which parameter is incorrect.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your `svaddr` created in `create_socket_server` is the correct one to use for sendto(). The problem is that you are returning pointers to local variables which will be garbage by the time you get to sendto().

Comment: "he suspected const struct sockaddr * svaddr as not correct" That's not what I said. I said basically what @ErkiAring said. (And also that you had an `&` that you shouldn't.)

Comment: And please, get rid of ALL of the assembly. Write a pure C program, with a `main` method, that exhibits the problem.

Comment: In `create_socket_client`: `retvals[1] = (int64_t)&claddr;` That's returning an address to a local variable which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kaylum - should I return it without the & -- e.g., retvals[1] = (int64_t) claddr?

Comment: No you shouldn't. You can't force the struct into a single `int64_t` (in fact, you shouldn't do that cast even for pointers). Pass in a pointer:`struct sockaddr_un *`  and fill in that buffer. Or `malloc` the struct and return that address to the caller (making sure caller frees it). Your whole `retvals` thing is a bit of a hack as it is essentially trying to return an untyped byte stream.

Comment: You mean to create the structure in a separate C function, then pass a pointer to it into that function?  My only problem is ultimately I'm calling these from NASM, so I'd still have the problem of passing a local variable back to NASM.  I may be able to create the struct in NASM.

Comment: @RTC222 The bad `&` was in `client_send`, which you now removed. The `&` in `create_socket_server` isn't wrong, but the fact that you're using it to make a dangling pointer is. And do you not understand that had you given us an example without NASM, your problem would be solved by now?

Comment: I'm creating the struct sockaddr_un in NASM because that looks like the problem based on the other comments on this question, as well as yours.  The struct was created locally in C and the pointer passed back, but the local var struct in C is out of scope when the pointer is used later.  The NASM side is limited to passing parameters and making the call, which it does correctly.  But the canonical way to pass to and from C is to create the object pointed to in the calling function (NASM).  You did call out the pointer to that struct as the problem, which is appears to be.

Comment: I'll post back when complete.

Comment: My point is to rewrite the calling function in C, not to not post the calling function.

Comment: If I rewrite the caller in C, I would do the same thing - create the struct in the caller and pass a pointer to the client create program.  I have to do that in NASM because this is called from NASM and that's where I need it.

Comment: I'm not saying you have to rewrite your full program in C. I'm saying for purposes of this question, you should write a minimal calling function in C.

Comment: If I have problems with NASM and the problem is still not solved, I'll do that and disassemble before posting.  I think I can solve it now, however.

Comment: No, don't disassemble before posting! Post the C here!

Comment: No, I'll post C here.  I'll disassemble to see what it tells me first.  But I won't post the disassembly here unless someone asks for it.